# Is it Ok to ask question about Play-by-email version of a card game?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering about the "off-topicness" of questions concerning the "electronic" version of an old card game called "Waving Hands". This game has been translated into a "Play-by-email" in the 90's and is still up and running.

So my question is : is it the right place to discuss stragegy about this game here. Or do we have to join the "FPS/RTS/Heavy3D" community of Gaming SE.

I think this audience will be better for this kind game, but I'm not sure that electronic version are allowed here.

(FYI the PBem version of the waving hands game is called "Firetop Mountain" You can have more info here (although it's not really necessary to answer my questiob) : (http://www.gamerz.net/fm/Main/)

Answer (score 5):

As long as the electronic (email/online) version has no major differences to the existing board or card game, it is well within the scope of this site.

I'm assuming that the strategy component of the game is the same when using email to play, so people playing the offline version will still find your question useful.

It's a different case if your question only applies to the electronic version - in that case, Gaming.SE might be a better place to ask.